# models in attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

There are numerous examples about relationships between models in Rails but they all seem to leave out the attr_accessible part of the model.

I'm looking for some best practices around the attr_accessible and I'm finding conflicting advice. Can/should I:

-- put foreign keys in the attr_accessible?

```
Class Post
  attr_accessible :name, :user_id

  belongs_to :user
end
Class User
  attr_accessible :first, :last

  has_many :posts
end
```

-- put complete models in the attr_accessible?

```
Class Post
  attr_accessible :name, :user

  belongs_to :user
end
Class User
  attr_accessible :first, :last

  has_many :posts
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to what Kaeros says, I would actually advise against allowing foreign key fields to be mass-assignable. The reason is that you're then opening up an easy way for someone to send a different user_id when adding a post. This is probably why the examples you're finding are not including foreign keys.

The best way to get around this is to use the collection builder method when adding a new post for a user:

```
user.posts.create(params[:post])
```

If you choose to not follow that advice, then it really depends on how you are mass-assigning the values. If your hash contains `:user_id`, then you should make that accessible, if it contains `:user`, go with that one. If you are unsure, you could always make both accessible.

Comment: And the github security issue of a few months ago was a foreign key thing - when updating an ssh key it was mistakenly allowing you to set the user_id (or equivalent) ie who the key belonged to, with the result that you could add your key to another user

Answer (score 0):

Using foreign keys in the attr_accessible seems to be normal and the default option to me. You can see [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html) that the api guide also uses this form.

Adding model names to attr_accessible also worked for me.

I prefer the first option, so i know easily that i am dealing with foreign keys